# How to detect browser close event in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser, dom-events

How to detect browser close event in Firefox browser? I want to do some clean up process in server side and we maintaining last logout time.
To achieve this need fire an ajax call when the user clicks logout or the browser is closed.
For IE the following code is working:

```
if (window.event.clientY < 0 && (window.event.clientX > (document.documentElement.clientWidth - 5) || window.event.clientX < 0)) {

        logoutUser();//logging out the user

        } 
}


function logoutUser(){

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera,
    //Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Logout.action", true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

How to do this in Firefox? Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

Use `onbeforeunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```

Comment: `onbeforeunload` with the returned string will show a popup to user and ask them if they are sure they want to leave the page

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('unload',fn,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var closedWindow = function() {
    //code goes here
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('unload', closedWindow, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    // pre IE9 browser
    window.attachEvent('onunload', closedWindow);
}
```