# Detecting FF browser being closed (X) in 2018

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, webkit, mozilla

A requirement from the customer is to immediately detect that the browser is closed and canceling the session opened from it. This calls for detecting the browser closing event with the onbeforeunload and calling there our logout Servlet from a XmlHttpRequest. It may have worked in the past but today it doesn't work anymore.

After hours of googling and testing I could not come up with a decent solution that detects browser closing on Firefox. I can more or less detect it on other browsers but not on FF. Actually I cannot even catch 100% of the times the event of a tab being closed. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Frustrating.

Does anyone in 2018 has a working example to share, that effectively detects on new FF browsers the closing event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect browser close event in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757485/how-to-detect-browser-close-event-in-firefox)

Comment: Not duplicated because all those examples are old or not working.

Comment: You should really post a snipped of the code that's not working to get more help :)